# Can't get webpack hot module replacement to work

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've set up WebPack successfully - it's compiling my babel and SCSS files just fine, and I got the watch functionality to work fine. But I'd also like to work with the Hot Module Replacement - and I'm having difficulties getting it going. When I load the dev server in my browser it shows `Cannot resolve module 'webpack/hot/dev-server'`. My config looks like this:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import wpServer from 'webpack-dev-server';

var compiler = webpack({
    entry: [
        './src/core.js',
        'webpack/hot/dev-server'
    ],
    output: {
        path: outPath,
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolveLoader: { root: path.join(MODULE_PATH, "node_modules") },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
          { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
    watch: true
});

var server = new wpServer(compiler, {
    contentBase: outPath,
    hot: true,
    quiet: false,
    noInfo: false,
    lazy: true,
    filename: "main.js",
    watchDelay: 300,
    headers: { "X-Custom-Header": "yes" },
    stats: { colors: true },
});
server.listen(8080, "localhost", function() {});
```

and my index.html contains:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
<script src='main.js'></script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You cannot combine webpack-dev-server lazy mode with HMR. The lazy mode only recompiles when on HTTP request. HMR relies on watchers that recompile on change. Use `lazy: false` instead or just omit it.

Comment: I've posted a small explanation about how HMR works and what's required to make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016683/what-aspect-of-hot-module-replacement-is-this-article-for/37022884#37022884

Answer (score 14):

If you installed `webpack-dev-server` globally, which is `npm install webpack-dev-server -g`, try install it locally (just remove the option `-g`).

I solved this problem by doing so.

Comment: It seems that the `--hot` option is looking for some files locally. Maybe there's a way to say they're installed globally. Cause installing dev-server locally and globally feels awkward.

Comment: @yvesamsellem I'd assume this issue has to do with how `webpack-dev-server` determines the base dir of your project. I checked the docs and it looks like the utility exposes a `--content-base` option to override the default. Either way, installing it as a local `devDependency` should be the preferred approach to maintain consistency across platforms.

Answer (score 6):

---

**IMPORTANT**

---

If you are using **webpack@2.x.x.beta** make sure you install

```
webpack-dev-server@2.0.0-beta
```

Just running `npm install webpack-dev-server` won't play nice with
   webpack 2.

This will probably only be true while version 2 is still in beta.

---

I also struggled getting this working since the documentation on this topic is very fragmented.

Found this simple working example:

> https://github.com/ahfarmer/webpack-hmr-starter-dev-server-api

Code is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue. I fixed it by installing webpack itself locally.
To install webpack as a local dev dependency:
`npm i -D webpack`